# The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type Optional

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, java-11

I have a spring project where i have a boolean method which uses optional to filter through a set of requests. Im getting an error when i try return `request.isEmpty()`, I looked it up and i might be using an older version of java but is there any alternative way to say `request.isEmpty()` without having to update my version of java as Im worried if i update it, it will affect the rest of my project

This is my code for the method

```
private boolean hasNoDaysOffOnShiftDate(List<Request> requests, ShiftParams params) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // for string
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); // for localdate

    // Shift start date in LocalDate
    String shiftDate = (params.start).format(formatter);
    LocalDate formatDateTime = LocalDate.parse(shiftDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Shift date in date format " + formatDateTime);

    Optional<Request> request = requests.stream().filter(req -> req.getStatus() == Status.Accepted)
            .filter(req -> isDayOffOnShiftDate(req, formatDateTime)).findAny();
    return request.isEmpty();

}
```

The error I am getting is

> The method `isEmpty()` is undefined for the type `Optional<Request>`

I am using this version of java

> java.version=1.8.0_73

Comment: funny that you use `SimpleDateFormat`, but at the same time `Optional` - which implies java-8...

Comment: @JaneRyan Optional is not a List, it's also not a request. first execute .get() on the optional, then .isEmpty()

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your Java 8 version is pretty old. Compare Java 8 update 73, with the current latest Java 8 update 212.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`Optional#isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()) is a Java 11 method, which is a shortcut for Java 8's [`!Optional#isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--).

```
return !request.isPresent();
```

Comment: I was getting compile-time error as "could not find symbol isEmpty()" in my spring boot. This solution fixed it. I had java 8

Comment: saved my time. Thanks!